# cyanogenmod 7 mytouch 3g cannot connect to wireless

Tags: wi-fi, cyanogenmod, htc-mytouch-3g-slide

Upgraded to cyanogenmod 7.0.3-slide a week ago. Just today the wireless (802.11G) quit working. Wifi Analyzer just shows "Nothing yet ;)". Rebooting doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remove the saved networks and it started working again.

Hope this helps someone else.